# import io.restassured.RestAssured cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, rest-assured

I am not able to resolve the error in Eclipse IDE
The type io.restassured.RestAssured is not accessible. I recreated the project, cleaned it, create POM again but still the issue. Below is my POM.

`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>DemoProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>DemoProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>18</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

```
type here
```

`

I am using latest dependencies from maven.

Answer (score 0):

Using exactly the same pom file, I had no issues resolving the Rest Assured.
It must be something else. Network related issues.
Try purging the local maven repository:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>DemoProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: After spending 3 hours it was finally solved. The problem was in Eclipse IDE. When a new java project is created it is by default creating module-info.java file. This is the problem. It needs to be unchecked so that Eclipse doesn't create it.